# IE halts loading HTML page abruptly

Tags: apache, ssl, internet-explorer-8, https

Understanding that my problem could have a very vast scope of possibilities, I'll accept the answer that points me to something that I might have missed.

My software's client is facing this issue of page stopping loading in the middle and that too happens randomly. As usual, this does not happen in out network even with guys doing VPN from remotest parts of the world. The page is only 14 KB.

Its a web-based software that serves HTML via Apache over HTTPS. Client is using IE8 browsers.

We did network trace and found that not only number of bytes differ from our end to the trace at client's end, even encrypted packet sequence also differ (after a while in the stream). But that happens for successful request too!

Has someone experienced similar issue? What could corrupt the stream?

PS: I'm not too optimistic on getting answer here and going to post it to serverfault anyway. If someone thinks its off-topic, please feel free to close it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the [operation aborted scenario](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx) which throws an error in IE7, but stops processing silently in IE8.

> The HTML file is being parsed, and encounters a script block. The script block contains inline script which creates a new element and attempts to add it to the BODY (document.body.appendChild(newElem)) element before the closing BODY tag has been encountered by the parser. Note that if I removed the highlighted DIV element, then this problem would not occur because the script block’s immediate parent would be BODY, and the script block’s immediate parent is immune to this problem.
>
> Unfortunately the operation aborted dialog was always thrown at the top-level of a web page, even if the problem occured in an iframe. In fact, in most scenarios that we encountered, ad injection in an iframe was usually the root cause of this error. After the user dismissed the error dialog, Internet Explorer would navigate away from the page.